# Getting both text and html parts of email with Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: multipart, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have spent all day looking for this, and I can't find it.  I am astounded nobody has posted an example of this.

In our app, displaying the text/plain version of the email is sufficient most of the time.  But, there are a couple of spots where we'd like to plop the HTML into a Rich Text control.  Basically, to see the inline images in context.  I can do the string replacements to point at the image attachments on disk.

I'm new to Microsoft Graph.  I know a little about emails, but have never dug into the guts very deep, before.  I've seen a couple of snippets in my searches that come close, but they all leave out some of the setup code, and my Graph and email knowledge isn't sufficient to fill in the holes, yet.

One snippet from ChatGPT is tantalizing:

```
foreach (var bodyPart in message.Body.Content)
{
    if (bodyPart.Type == BodyType.Text)
    {
        textBody = bodyPart.Content.ToString();
    }
    else if (bodyPart.Type == BodyType.Html)
    {
        htmlBody = bodyPart.Content.ToString();
    }
}
```

That looks like exactly what I want.  But, it doesn't show me how to set that up.  I've searched for some of the lines of text in that sample, but haven't found the page that ChatGPT pulled that from.

I've asked the Graph-experienced people on my team, and none had a quick solution at hand.

At this point, I'm about to punt, and just open the message twice.  Once with requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'"); and once with requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='html'");  This is a low volume site, so the extra overhead shouldn't be a problem.  It just feels dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to [get MIME content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message) of the message, where you can get

- Plain text message
- Message with alternative content (i.e., **in both plain text and HTML**)
- Reply message with the original message attached
- Text message with attachments of image, audio, video, or application files
- Other message constructs

```
GET /me/
GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/$value
```

Regarding your snippet, `message.Body.Content` is not a collection, so the generated snippet will never work.

Making two requests

- one with `Prefer: outlook.body-content-type='text'`
- and the second one with `Prefer: outlook.body-content-type='html'`

seems to be overhead, so I would prefer MIME content and parse what you need from it

To read MIME content with C# SDK

```
using var stream = await graphServiceClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Content.GetAsync();
using var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
```

Comment: I appreciate the input.  The page you sent me is for the REST API.  I've been searching, and I can't find how to grab the MIME sections with the C# SDK calls

Comment: @Mighty Updated the answer with the code for C# SDK v5 to get MIME content.